# How to change the width / height of Shell Flyout menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am using a Shell Flyoutmenu in my Xamarin Forms application.  Thing are fine except that my options in the menu are very short and the tray goes very wide and long.  Is there a way to change the width and height of the FlyoutMenu?  I tried adding a `WidthRequest` to the shell object itself to adjust the width but it did not seem to make a difference.  Here is what my flyout currently looks like.

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is the AppShell.xaml file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:UniversalCheckInApp.Views"
   x:Class="UniversalCheckInApp.AppShell"
   BackgroundColor="#1E1F26" 
   FlyoutBackgroundColor="#D0E1F9">

<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#1E1F26" Padding="4,4,4,4">
        <Label Text="Navigation" TextColor="#D0E1F9" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" Margin="4,4,4,4" />
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="16,0,4,0" >
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#1E1F26" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                   TextDecorations="Underline"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>

<FlyoutItem Title="Configuration" >

    <ShellContent x:Name="scNetworkConfiguration" Title="Network Configuration"  >
        <views:NetworkConfiguration />
    </ShellContent>

    <ShellContent x:Name="scDataConfiguration" Title="Data Configuration">
        <views:FormFieldConfiguration />
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Collect Data">
    <ShellContent x:Name="scCollectData" Title="Collect Data">
        <views:DataCollection />
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>


<FlyoutItem Title="About">
    <ShellContent x:Name="scAbout" Title="About">
        <views:About />
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Hi , could you show the `Xaml` code of screenshot ?

Comment: Junior Jiang - I have shown the XAML.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for sharing  . I will check it ,if solution will update here.

Comment: It is not possible to do that, feel free to open an issue in [Xamarin.Forms Issues](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **FlyoutWidth** as a property of the shell.

```cs
<Shell
    x:Class="Example.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
    FlyoutWidth="200"

    <ShellContent Title="Home" 
                    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}"/>

</Shell>
```

Comment: Yep - they seem to have added the capability as some point (Maybe in Maui) which is great.  I am now using the flyout menu in the Maui version of my app.

Answer (score 2):

On Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.1829-pre6 the two attached properties `Shell.FlyoutWidth` and `Shell.FlyoutHeight` of type double [have been added](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/12161) allowing to set the width and height of the Shell flyout.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the comment from Elvis Xia at MSFT - this is not possible.  I have abandoned the use of the Shell Flyout menu in my app so I did not open an issue with MSFT as Elvis suggested.  If this is important to other people, I suggest you raise the issue with MSFT so the feature can be included in a future release.